# Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':compileClasspath'. Find for dependencies inside jar in CircleCI build

Tags: java, gradle, maven-plugin, circleci

I am getting this error in my CircleCI build.

```
* What went wrong:
Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':compileClasspath'.
> Could not find com.monederobingo:libs:0.0.1.
  Required by:
      project :
```

`com.monederobingo:libs:0.0.1` is a library that only exists in my local maven `.m2` directory.

I have this dependency specified in my `gradle.config`.

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal()
}
dependencies {
    ...
    compile 'com.monederobingo:libs:0.0.1'
}
```

Is there a way to include this `jar` in CircleCI build?

UPDATE: I have tried to include the `jar` in the project using these steps: https://discuss.gradle.org/t/how-to-include-dependencies-in-jar/19571/5

However, I'm still getting the same error in `Circle CI` build.

Comment: why not include the jar in your project if its not supposed to be shared on any server?

Comment: I have that dependency declared in my `gradle.config`. You mean including it directly in some folder in the project?

Comment: yes. or else the artifact would need to be present in some repository, right for the CircleCI to fetch it. Correct me if I am wrong.